# How do I store a string memory address like "7fefe05a8" into a pointer/int variable in C++ so that I can do bit masking on it?

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, hex

I read from a file with memory addresses in the form `7fefe05a8`,`7fefe0590`etc

I would like to store them in an pointer/integer/long etc variable and do some operations on them e.g bit masking.

```
// store "7fefe05a8" from file into pointer variable
lastFourBits = pointer & 0x00000000f;
```

Comment: Just use [strtoul](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) to convert the string to an unsigned long.

Comment: Do *not* use a pointer-typed variable to perform the masking on, but a suitable integer variable.

Comment: If you're not actually going to be dereferencing them (with `*`) then just treat them as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtoul()` function to perform conversion. `str` pointer should contain pointer to your string.

```
char              *endptr, *str;
unsigned long int pointer;

str = ... /* assign pointer to your string */
pointer = strtoul(str, &endptr, 16);

if (endptr == str) { /* no digits were found */
...
}

if (*endptr != '\0')  { /* further characters after number */
...
}
```